# How to resize [ sliderTabs ] slider in Mobile

Tags: jquery

Using below code which is not working

```
var supportsOrientationChange = "onorientationchange" in window,
    orientationEvent = supportsOrientationChange ? "orientationchange" : "resize";

window.addEventListener(orientationEvent, function() {    
    var height= window.innerHeight; 
    $contentDivsContainer.height(height);   
}, false);
```

Comment: http://lopatin.github.io/sliderTabs/

Comment: do you have any idea ,,how to resize tab's contant in mobile view while changing oriantation here is the link http://lopatin.github.io/sliderTabs/